# How to Find Records in MongoDB where one field = a second Field ( basic query )

Tags: mongodb

Coming from a SQL background I was expecting this to be easy.  I just want to select records where one field equals a different field in the same record.

```
db.postRecon.find({"order.packages.tracking_number":  {$eq :"ticketNumber"}})
```

also tried:

```
db.postRecon.find({"order.packages.tracking_number":  "ticketNumber"})
```

What am I missing?  This is a pretty basic sort of query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mongo 3.6+ we can use the following:

```js
db.postRecon.find({ $expr: { $eq: ["$order.packages.tracking_number", "$this.ticketNumber"] } })
```

Comment: that didn't work - but this does.  If you correct it I will mark it right   db.postRecon.find({ $expr: { $eq: ["$order.packages.tracking_number", "$this.ticketNumber"] } })

Comment: @MartinThompson Thanks for the correction...I'm not in front of Robo3T at the moment, apologies.

Comment: @MartinThompson Robo3T is a "free" IDE for Mongo, and for what it is, it's good.  They have a proprietary version called Studio3T as well.

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience in this case you have to use aggregation like in this example.

```
db.people.aggregate([{
$project : {
    "CONDITION" : {
        $eq : ["$first_name", "$nome"] 
    },
    "document" : "$$ROOT"   
} }, {$match:{"CONDITION":true}}]);
```

In this case I want to make a comparison between 2 fields of the same collection, namely **first_name** and **nome** , and find only the record where the 2 fields have the same value.

As you can see first I use a project to create my **CONDITION** field which can be true or false; in the project statement I move also all the document data, otherwise I would find only **_id** and **CONDITION** after the projectection stage.

Finally I filter on the **CONDITION** field.

I don't know if there is a better way to achieve this goal, I think it is indeed quite too complicated but , my opinion of course, the mongodb syntax is more complicated that it should be, expecially compared to the linearity and elegance of sql.

Comment: Wow. really?  That has changed my view of MongoDB completely.  I can't believe that for such a simple query you need to aggregate. I might even look at another noSQL database all together!